# Symbolic Real Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

I'd like to define a symbolic real positive definite matrix. For the 2 x 2 example, I thought I could define four real variables using `$Assumptions = {a,b,c,d} \esc elem \esc Reals`. And then define the positive definite matrix using `MatrixPD = Transpose[{{a,b},{c,d}}].{{a,b},{c,d}}]`.

However `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[MatrixPD]` returns False. Is this because, I have not defined the assumptions sufficiently to guarantee that MatrixPD will be positive definite, or is it because of a limitation of PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ.

I also tried the following. The manaul includes the following symbolic example
`PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[{{1, a}, {-Conjugate[a], 1}}]`
Since I had defined "a" to be real, I assumed I could modify this to be
`PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[{{1, a}, {-a, 1}}]`
However, this returned False. Am I not asserting the assumption that "a" is real properly or is something else going wrong?

Comment: Assumptions are only taken into consideration by a few functions and not all; I doubt that `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ` does. The docs for `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ` say that it returns true only for *explicitly* positive definite matrices, which I take to mean numerical ones.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks this is helpful. Another step, I notice is that the use of Transpose[A].A requires that A be invertible. So my question reduces to generating a symbolic invertible matrix.

Comment: I think your assumptions allows for  semi definite matrices: E.g. `{a, b, c, d}={2, 3, 4, 6}; m={{20, 30}, {30, 45}}`

Comment: @DanielHuber this is a helpful example. I see that {{2,3},{4,6}} is not invertible, so indeed this is a missing requirement. Do you have a suggestion for generating a symbolic invertible matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure how general this is but one approach to generating an invertible matrix is to generate lower and upper matrices. Then A = LU is invertible.

Comment: Hi, you could e.g. create a diagonal matrix m with positive diagonal elements. Then you take some rotation r and calculate: r.m.Transpose[r]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any positive real matrix has positive eigenvalues, so you can construct the matrix by:

```
n = 2;
diag = Array[e, n];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
sym = FullSimplify[Transpose[b] . DiagonalMatrix[diag] . b]
```

So sym is the general form of the matrix. To be positive definite, you then need ensure only that the n elements of diag (in the n=2 case, this is e[1] and e[2]) are positive.